# devexpress customer popup edit from validation doesn't work while adding

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, devexpress

I am using the Dev-express in my project for data that should be shown in a grid.
While i am using popup mode the validation is not working its directly `modelstate.valid` is getting true, but the values are null and/or not valid.
How can I solve this?

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    try
    {
        //code is here the control is coming inside if ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You might be better asking this on the devexpress support site itself.

(That said the site is down, once again!)

Comment: How does the controller method look  what does the model object look like that you are sending back? whithout this info one can only guess what your problem is...TLDR; show code